# Error when using static_assert on Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, static-assert

I use Netbeans to develop a Java / JNI / C++ application. In my c++ classes, I use static_assert and Netbeans displays an error:

```
static_assert(myvariable == 2, "My test.") ;
```

The error is:

```
Unable to resolve identifier static_assert
```

And yes, I've included "type_traits".

But, **the code compiles and runs perfectly**. Is that a bug from NetBeans?

Comment: `static_assert` is a C++11 feature. Did you enable C++11 for your c++ compilation step?

Comment: Yes, I use the flag "-std=c++11". But compilation and execution are fine, it's just netbeans which display the error.

Comment: What's your version of NB? You can also let the Parser reparse your project and check IDE log if there's an error.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the last comment. The version is 8.0.2.

Comment: I had similar issues with NetBeans pointing errors in the code, but I was able to compile and run it. So I guess NetBeans has really issues to handle properly C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used C++ on NetBeans for many months now, and it appears to be one of the many bugs of NetBeans with C++. Many times, static_assert or other functions were labeled red as an error, but compiled perfectly. I will edit if this bug is fixed in a future NetBeans release.

[EDIT] it also happens with `template<typename T> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, INT32>::value>::type`. `::type` is flagged as being an error, but everything compiles fine.