# Best way to dispatch on the good template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have three functions that do almost the same thing, but the process is a little bit different according to the parameters type:

```
template<typename T> void Func1(const T *in, T *out)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, INT8>::value
                  || std::is_same<T, UINT8>::value
                  || std::is_same<T, INT16>::value
                  || std::is_same<T, UINT16>::value, "");
    //...
}

template<typename T> void Func2(const T *in, T *out)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, INT32>::value || std::is_same<T, UINT32>::value, "");
    //...
}

template<typename T> void Func3(const T *in, T *out)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, float>::value || std::is_same<T, double>::value, "");
    //...
}
```

But I don't want the user to have to decide which function call, so I try to do it automatically. Unfortunately so far (I am a C++ beginner), the only way I know would be:

```
template<typename T> void Function(const T *in, T *out)
{
    if (std::is_same<T, UINT8>::value
        || std::is_same<T, UINT16>::value
        || std::is_same<T, INT8>::value
        || std::is_same<T, INT16>::value)
    {
        Func1(in, out);
        return ;
    }

    if ( std::is_same<T,INT32>::value || std::is_same<T,UINT32>::value )
    {
        Func2(in, out);
        return ;
    }

    if ( std::is_same<T,float>::value || std::is_same<T,float>:: double )
    {
        Func3(in, out);
        return ;
    }
}
```

I find this solution completely ugly, and I would like to know if something better/faster/more elegant is possible?

Comment: What is `unsigned float` and `unsigned double`?

Comment: @WhiZTiM : sorry, stupid copy/paste. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use C++11 or greater, you can use [type_traits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/) (SFINAE) :

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, INT8>::value 
            || std::is_same<T, UINT8>::value 
            || std::is_same<T, INT16>::value 
            || std::is_same<T, UINT16>::value>::type Function(const T*in, T*out)
{
    Func1(in, out);
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, INT32>::value 
            || std::is_same<T, UINT32>::value >::type Function(const T*in, T*out)
{
    Func2(in, out);
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, float>::value 
            || std::is_same<T, double>::value >::type Function(const T*in, T*out)
{
    Func3(in, out);
}
```

Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4f000fa6ffa8f19

Or if you can't use C++11 or greater, you can use overload instead of template:

```
void Function(const UINT8 *int, UINT8 * out)
{
    Func1(in, out);
} 
...
void Function(const UINT32 *int, UINT32 * out)
{
    Func2(in, out);
} 
...
```

Or you can use [template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) but, in this case, it's not really relevant (I leave it here, because it was in original answer):

```
template<typename T> Function(const T *in, T *out);

template<> void Function(const UINT8 *in, UINT8 * out)
{
    Func1(in, out);
}

template<> void Function(const INT8 *in, INT8 * out)
{
    Func1(in, out);
}

....
```

Comment: And instead of specialization, just use overload. But the preferred approach would be the SFINAE one for me.

Comment: @Jarod42 I add it in answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In your solution, I don't even need to call Func* anymore, I can juste copy the code inside the function. The only thing that does not compile is the "::type", but it does if I remove it. Why is that? (I haven't forgotten to add type_traits.

Comment: @FiReTiTi [std::enable_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/enable_if/) is defined to have `::type` only if condition is respected. `enable_if` exists whatever condition is true or false. So function exists only if return type is defined, ie, only if `enable_if<>::type` is defined. See [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error)

Comment: @FiReTiTi Also, using g++ with correct flag (ie `-std=c++11`), without `::type` I got an error, see example

Comment: If you don't use `::type` then you won't get SFINAE.

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me why not I get this warning: www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/TemplateWarning.png

Comment: @FiReTiTi hum... which compiler do you use ? with which flags ?

Comment: I guess it's because I use gcc with the flack -std=c++11

Comment: Maybe, use g++ -std=c++11 instead of gcc. Which version of gcc/g++ have you ?

Comment: I use: g++ (MacPorts gcc5 5.3.0_1) 5.3.0

Comment: @FiReTiTi You really need to post full errors, otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: Sorry guys, but it's a little bit messy with NetBeans? Here is the full error ( www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/Error2.txt ). I've removed the flag -std=c++11.

Comment: First error say that you have to add flag -std=c++11. If you can, you just have to use second solution : overload

Comment: But if I do I cannot use the C++14 tools... no?

Comment: You can use -std=c++14 also, my solution works without any modification for c++14

Comment: Yes, it's what I just did, but I still get an error with ::type ( www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/Error3.txt )

Comment: It's not error from my solution, but for TartanLlama's one

Comment: @FiReTiTi `is_one_of` is not in the `std` namespace, and neither is `disjunction` in your code.

Comment: Ok, I corrected it, but I still get an error with disjunction. So I have commented so far, just to understand the two different problems. I still have an error because of ::type ( www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/Error4.txt )

Comment: @FiReTiTi You have `::type::type` in your code. I'd recommend reading the cppreference documentation for SFINAE and `std::enable_if` and trying to understand how the code works before you use it.

Comment: I just double checked my code, and I have not ::type::type

Comment: @FiReTiTi It's in the error you posted. Maybe you should make a new question and post the real code you're having problems with.

Comment: @FiReTiTi Also, you use type `unsigned char` and I think you forget to put in list of authorized type for a function

Comment: @FiReTiTi is it possible to see code associated to this error (I think HistogramStretching.h) ?

Comment: @@@@@ and @@@@@@!!!!!!!!!! I was really annoyed to not being able to understand the problem, so I created an other file with just your code: ::type appeared as an error, but everything compiled fine. And then I remembered this discussion ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33114225/error-when-using-static-assert-on-netbeans ). So I cleaned the code from everything, and restarted NetBeans. Everything compiled fine, despite the fact that ::type appears as an error. I am so sorry I didn't think about the fact that NetBeans has real issues with C++.

Comment: You're welcome ;) And happy to see that is "only" a problem with Netbeans

Answer (score 4):

You could write a trait to check if a type is appears in a list. This version uses [`std::disjunction`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction) from C++17, but you can just copy-paste the implementation from the link.

```
template <typename F, typename... T>
using is_one_of = std::disjunction<std::is_same<F, T>...>;
```

Then use [`SFINAE`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) with [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) to select the overload (`std::enable_if_t` is C++14, use `typename std::enable_if<...>::type` if you're stuck with 11).

```
template<typename T> 
std::enable_if_t<is_one_of<T, uint8_t, int8_t, uint16_t, int16_t>::value>
Func(const T *in, T *out)
{
    std::cout << "1\n";
}

template<typename T> 
std::enable_if_t<is_one_of<T, uint32_t, int32_t>::value>
Func(const T *in, T *out)
{
    std::cout << "2\n";
}

template<typename T> 
std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value> 
Func(const T *in, T *out)
{
    std::cout << "3\n";
}
```

Note that you don't even need `Func1`, `Func2` and `Func3`, you can just make the different `Func` overloads do your processing.

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/705473c876ab5242)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The "is_one_of" generates an error. I've found "is_any_of" on google, but not "is_one_of".

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it: Unable to resolve identifier "is_one_of".

Comment: @FiReTiTi Did you include the implementation of `is_one_of` from my answer? Are you compiling with C++14?

Comment: Yes, is_one_of is included, but I just realized that std::disjunction is not supported. I am not really sure about the C++ version... how can I find it? And I had to use the flag -std=c++11 for other purposes in my program.

Comment: So it seems that I am stuck with C++ 11.

Comment: @FiReTiTi Then copy the implementation of `std::disjunction` which I linked to and use `std::enable_if` rather than `std::enable_if_t`.

Comment: I am looking to try to switch to C++14.

Comment: @FiReTiTi This answer will work for C++11, you just need to make the changes I mentioned.

Comment: I got that part, but I would rather make the upgrade instead of adding more code

Comment: Now it works (see my last answer to @Garf365), so you got my vote.

Comment: Thanks for your help!